# Rowspan and colspan from the begining of the table

Tags: html

Generally we make rowspan and colspan after the first column of the table. But in my case I want to draw a table like in this photo :

[image]

How to achieve it ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

table {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="12"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve these problems, imagine everything is expanded and each block is a significant part of the table definition. Using that information, you have 19 columns and 2 rows. From there you allocate your groups:

"Valeurs Cibles Cumulees" has a colspan of 4.

"Chronogramme" has a colspan of 12.

"Taches", "Source of Financement", and "Responsables" have a rowspan of 2.

Comment: To add to this, when making your table it is important to start with the <tr>s for everything in the first row first, after those are done then create the <tr>s for the second row.